# esx5 debian VM vlan setup

Tags: debian, virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-esx, vlan

i have a server with ESX5, have a switch with about 20 vlans, this is how setup the trunk port

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/1
 description ToOper
 port link-type trunk
 undo port trunk allow-pass vlan 1
 port trunk allow-pass vlan 2 to 14
 stp disable
 ntdp enable
 ndp enable
 bpdu enable
```

then, i created a standar switch(`sw1`) using the vSphere Client, the VLAN ID is set to `All (4095)`, i also created a VM with Debian 6, with a NIC connected to `sw1`, now, i want to configure this NIC for a selected group of vlans

```
auto vlan10
iface vlan10 inet static
    address 11.10.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    mtu 1500
    vlan_raw_device eth0

auto vlan14
iface vlan14 inet static
    address 11.10.1.65
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    mtu 1500
    vlan_raw_device eth0
```

so, when i restart the network using `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, i got this error

```
Reconfiguring network interfaces...SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
vlan14: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFNETMASK: No such device
SIOCSIFBRDADDR: No such device
vlan14: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFMTU: No such device
vlan14: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
Failed to bring up vlan14.
done.
```

this is just part of the error, so, my questions is:
is this possible?, i mean, what i'm trying to achieve using ESX Virtual Machines, VLANS, etc
is this a Debian problem?
can be solved?
i've read about a file named `z25_persistent-net.rules` in Debian but it doesn't exist in my installation.
in the

In the `vSphere Networking for ESX5` guide, you can read:
*If you enter 0 or leave the option blank, the port group can see only untagged (non-VLAN) traffic. If you
enter 4095, the port group can see traffic on any VLAN while leaving the VLAN tags intact.*

So, in theory, it should work, right?

Hope you can help me up with this one

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vlan` package was not installed in my system, after a successfull install, everything is OK